# New installed Ubuntu 18.04 freezes

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, 18.04, freeze

I've just installed Ubuntu 18.04 instead of Ubuntu 16.04 which was working just fine 
After installing Ubuntu 18.04, it freezes a lot, especially directly after logging in. If I tried to log in with another theme it freezes before logging in. Sometimes it even freezes before the login screen appear.

I read a couple of posts stating that it can be a graphics driver problem.

I have HP Pavilion dv7 laptop. I think it has an Intel graphics card and I read that it's driver is installed by default in all Ubuntu versions.

I also tried installing gdm from Alt+Ctrl+F2 but it said "no candidate"

How can I solve this problem?
I can't use my laptop and I'm writing this post using my iPhone.

Comment: I just reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score -1):

The original answer is on [superuser forum](https://superuser.com/a/1083166/617285). The next command resolved my issue.

```
systemctl reboot --firmware-setup
```